# NodeJS open library with Cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Hey is there a way to open a Website with **Cookies** in NodeJs via the [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) library?

I've been looking for a solution to parse the Cookies like a HTTP header in the Option argument of the `open` library!

```js
open(URL, {
    header: {
      secrets: 1234,
    },
    method: 'GET'
  });
```

Comment: You can pass a token as part of the url and make your server then set the respective cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

That would require the browsers supported a command line API for setting cookies, and that `open` supported it.

They don't.

Comment: Is there another library, which should do that?

Comment: Again, it would depend on browsers supporting a command line API for setting cookies, which they don't.